# Lambda calculus to scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, lisp, lambda-calculus, sicp

Is the following the correct way to "map" how a lambda function looks to how it would be written in scheme?

*(λx.x+1) 5* ↦ `(lambda (x) (+ x 1) 5)`

Additionally, how are lambda functions 'named' in the formal notation? Is there something that corresponds to this:

**Add One** = *(λx.x+1)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(λx.x+1)5* is an *application* to the argument 5. In Scheme code this would be equivalent to:

```
((lambda (x) (+ x 1)) 5)
```

Here the `(lambda (x) (+ x 1))` constitutes the function, and it must be placed in a function call context by wrapping it in parentheses with its arguments.

As far as naming in formal notation is concerned, this is not a feature of the lambda calculus proper. In texts it is often found that some sort of identifier notation is used to facilitate the expression of combinations; it seems like very simple identifiers are usually preferred in these cases. This is really mathematical notation, not programming notation. I have seen both of these:

```
A ≡ λx.x+1
A = λx.x+1
```

Comment: there is no naming in lambda calculus though. the naming is a meta notation, not part of LC itself.

Comment: @WillNess -- true enough, not in the lambda calculus proper; but formal texts that cover the lambda calculus commonly use some sort of identifier notation to express combinations more concisely. I'll add a note to emphasize that this is not part of the actual lambda calculus.